# How many cycles of length $k$ in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In the symmetrical group $S_n$, how many cycles of length $k$ can we form? 
After some research I am tempted to say $\frac{n!}k$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you mean cycles as in the element itself is a plain cycle permutation of order $k$, or cycle in the sense that you have a cyclic subgroup of order $k$ generated by an element?

Comment: For exemple, In S9, the permutation (12)(345)(6)(78)(9) contains 1 cycle of length 3, two cycles of length 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hints:**

- A cycle of length $k$ permutes $k$ elements and leaves the remaining $n-k$ alone. How many ways are they of choosing which $k$ elements the cycle permutes?
- Once we've chosen $k$ elements to permute, we need to work out how many ways there are to permute them. Suppose your $k$ elements are $a_1, \ldots, a_k$. $a_1$ can go to any of $a_2, \ldots,  a_k$ - say it goes to $a_i$. Then $a_i$ can go to any of $a_2, \ldots, a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}, \ldots a_k$, and so on. How many possible permutations are there? Try some small values of $k$ if you get stuck.

Comment: I think we have n!/(n-k)! different ways of choosing k elements. Then we have k! ways to order our chosen elements. Am I right? So (n!/(n-k)!)k! cycles of length k in Sn?

Comment: Not quite. We have ${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ ways of choosing $k$ elements. There aren't quite that many ways to order the elements: since this is a cycle, it doesn't matter which element you start with (i.e. the cycle $(a\ b \ c)$ is the same as the cycle $(c \ a\ b)$).

Comment: Ok so since we are considering cycles, we have less than k! ways to order our chosen elements. Since we have k multiple ways to represent a cycle of length k, for k=3:(abc)=(cab)=(bca), is it correct to say that we have k!/k ways to permute our chosen k elements? So do we end up with n!k!/(n-k)!k!k = n!/(n-k)!k number of cycles?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A cycle of length $k$ can be constructed by first choosing $k$ elements out of $n$ and this can be done in $C(n,k)$ ways. Further the chosen $k$ elements are to be arranged in cyclic (*circular*) order and that can be done in $(k-1)!$ ways. So, in all there will be $C(n,k).(k-1)!$ such cycles.