# Notation of $\sum_n$ : A Formula for the Number of $\sigma \in \sum_n$ of $(c_1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, c_n)$

Tags: combinatorics

Define the type of $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$ to be a sequence $(c_1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, c_n)$
where $c_i$ is the number of cycles in $\sigma$ of length $i$.

Then find a formula for the number of $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$ of $(c_1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, c_n)$

---

Above is the exercise from the textbook of Combinatorics

What does the notation $\Sigma_n$ refer to?

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the set of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Then if the $c_n = 1$, there exist $1$ cases or or $(n-1)!$ for $\sigma$?

Comment: how many permutations can you count that have one cycle of length $n$? You may find this useful:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165684/how-many-cycles-of-length-k-in-s-n